# Why won't this work? (tkinter, python and functions)

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So this is my code, and it is basically like a tkinter 'app' to work as a calculator, clock, and have a game(more details will be added soon), but there are many things I want to do with my current version:
*EDIT* new version, can I print the time and game bit to a canvas-- answer code answer please!

```
from Tkinter import *
from sys import *
from datetime import *
import time

print 'LOADING'
toolbar_width = 40


for i in range(toolbar_width):
    time.sleep(0.1) # do real work here
    # update the bar
    sys.stdout.write("-")
    sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write("\n")


sys.stdout.write("\n")

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Home Laptop\Downloads\favicon.ico')
root.wm_title("SimpleOS")

p = Text(root, height = 2, width = 30) 
p.pack()


def time_app():
    t = raw_input('Would you like the time in hh:mm:ss, dd.mm.yy, or both (Type either h for the first option, d for the second, and b for the third): ')
    now=datetime.now()
    cy = now.year
    cm = now.month
    cd = now.day
    ch = now.hour
    cm1 = now.minute
    cs = now.second
    if t == 'h':
        print '%s:%s:%s' %(ch,cm1,cs)
        sys.exit()
        time.sleep(3)
    elif t == 'd':
        print '%s.%s.%s' %(cd,cm,cy)
        time.sleep(3)
        sys.exit()
    elif t == 'b':
        print '%s.%s.%s/%s:%s:%s' %(cd,cm,cy,ch,cm1,cs)
        time.sleep(3)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        sys.exit()


def calculate():
    i = float(raw_input('Enter your first number: '))
    ii = float(raw_input('Enter your second number: '))
    op = raw_input('Enter exactly: *,/,+ or -, with no quotation marks: ')
    ord1 = raw_input("To do the calculation in the order: i ---> ii, type 'a', to do it in this order: ii ---> i, type 'b', both with no quotes: ")
    if ord1 == 'a':
        if op == '*':
            value = str(i*ii)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)
        elif op == '/':
            value = str(i/ii)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)
        elif op == '+':
            value = str(i+ii)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)
        elif op == '-':
            value = str(i-ii)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)
        else:
            print 'UNEXPECTED ERROR'
            sys.exit()
    elif ord1 == 'b':
        if op == '*':
            value = str(ii*i)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)
        elif op == '/':
            value = str(ii/i)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)
        elif op == '+':
            value = str(ii+i)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)
        elif op == '-':
            value = str(ii-i)
            p.delete(1.0, END)
            p.insert(END, value)


def RPG():
    charChoice = raw_input('Would you like to be a ')    


app1 = ("Calculator")
app2 = ("Clock")
app3 = ("RPG")
w = Button(root, text="Calculator",command=calculate )
x = Button(root, text="Clock", command=time_app )
y = Button(root, text="RPG", command=RPG)

w.pack(side=LEFT)
x.pack(side=LEFT)
y.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
time.sleep(5)
sys.exit()
```

And I want to find out how to print the input to a tkinter canvas, not the idle shell. How do I do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few thing causing problems for you.

`op = raw_input('Enter exactly: *,/,+ or -, with quotation marks: ')`

I'm not sure why you're asking for quotes. If it's to make it a string then you don't need that as raw_input gives you what's typed as a string. And because none of your if statements are checking for the operation with quotes `if op == '*':` you will always get unexpected error.

Now to write to your Text widget all you need is to replace your print with these lines

```
p.delete(1.0, END) # Removes all text already in widget
p.insert(END, mytext) # Insert your text where the end of the cursor is
                      # This does not need to be a string
```

I would suggest changing the print line to `value = i*ii` and then outside your if statement have

```
p.delete(1.0, END)
p.insert(END, value)
```

This way you don't need to repeat that for every if statement.